# How to count each record and display it as a number per person, SQL

Tags: sql

I have a need to display a sequence number column in a table that lists the count of each record for a person in a Job history table. Each history record has a Job Start Date and the number should be listed in the chronological order of the dates.
This is how I want it to look-

```
EmployeeID SeqNo. JobStartDate
A0001        1     2006/02/02
A0001        2     2008/04/01
A0001        3     2009/03/01
A0002        1     2005/01/01
A0002        2     2005/04/01
A0003        1     2006/09/01
A0003        2     2007/01/01
A0003        3     2008/01/01
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? do you want us to write a query for you?  if so, can you post the schema of the table you want to query?

Comment: SQL is 2005. Yes I want to know how to display the Sequence number. The History table doesn't have a sequence number for each of the employee record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005+ or any other version of SQL that supports `ROW_NUMBER() and PARTITION` then you can do something like this

```
SELECT EmployeeID, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY JobStartDate) AS SeqNo,
    JobStartDate
FROM [TABLE]
```

The row_number creates a unique row based on the partition (which acts like a GROUP BY) and the ORDER BY.

Comment: Thank you Justin!! This is exactly what I needed. I appreciate everyone who helped.